# Rails: Creating a Multiple Model Form over n association levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, webforms

Can anyone tell me why the form at the end of this question isn't working like it should?

- Save doesn't work
- The select-helper doesn't select the
  value according to the object `@kid`

The whole thing is based on Rails 2.2.2 and no, upgrading to Rails 2.3 to solve this problem isn't an option. :-)

I used [this recipe](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/fr_arr/multiple_models_one_form.pdf) to build the multiple model form.

```
# CLASS GRANDPARENT
class Grandparent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parents 
end

# CLASS PARENT
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :grandparent, :class_name => "Grandparent", :foreign_key => "grandparent_id"
  has_many :kids
end

# CLASS KID
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Parent", :foreign_key => "parent_id"

  # Virtual attribute setter for new self.parent.grandparent (Grandparent) attributes
  def new_grandparent_attributes=(_gp_attributes)
    self.parent.build_grandparent(_gp_attributes)
  end

  # Virtual attribute setter for existing self.parent.grandparent (Grandparent) attributes
  def existing_grandparent_attributes=(_gp_attributes)
    unless self.parent.grandparent.new_record?
      attributes = _gp_attributes[self.parent.grandparent.id.to_s]
      if attributes
        self.parent.grandparent.attributes = attributes
      else
        self.parent.grandparent.delete(grandparent)
      end
    end
  end

end

# CONTROLLER KIDS
class KidsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @kid = Kid.new
  end

  def edit
    @kid = Kid.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    params[:kid][:new_grandparent_attributes] ||= {}
    @kid = Kid.new(params[:kid])
  end

  def update
    params[:kid][:existing_grandparent_attributes] ||= {}
    @kid = Kid.find(params[:id])
  end

end


# THIS IS THE MULTI-MODEL FORM USED IN THE VIEW

<% form_for(@kid) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <% new_or_existing = @kid.parent.grandparent.new_record? ? 'new' : 'existing' %>
        <% prefix = "kid[#{new_or_existing}_grandparent_attributes][]" %>

        <% fields_for prefix, @kid.parent.grandparent do |g_f| -%>
            <p>
              <%= g_f.label :, 'Grandparent Name' %><br />
              <!-- THE FOLLOWING FORM DOESN'T CHANGE ACCORDING TO EXISTING @child -->
              <%= @grandparents = Entity.find(:all, :order => :name)
                g_f.collection_select(:name ,@grandparents, :id, :name) 
                %>
            </p>
        <% end %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name, "Kid Name" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <%= submit_tag 'Go' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, correct me if I am wrong but it doesn't appear that you are actually saving the object anywhere. In your create and update actions you are calling `new` and then not saving it.

To rectify this you could do:

```
def create
  params[:kid][:new_grandparent_attributes] ||= {}
  @kid = Kid.new(params[:kid])
  if @kid.save
    # successful save logic here
  else
    #failed save logic here
  end
end

def update
  params[:kid][:existing_grandparent_attributes] ||= {}
  @kid = Kid.find(params[:id])
  if @kid.update_attributes(params[:kid])
    #successful save logic here
  else
    #failed save logic here
  end
end
```

Then in your select box you are trying to find every record of `Entity`, not those fields of `Entity` that are related to @kid. In order to do this you'll have to set up a relationship between kid and grandparent.

```
# CLASS GRANDPARENT
class Grandparent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parents
  has_many :grand_kids, :through => :parents
end

# CLASS PARENT
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :grandparent, :class_name => "Grandparent", :foreign_key => "grandparent_id"
  has_many :kids
end

# CLASS KID
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Parent", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  belongs_to :grandparent

  # ...
```

This way you can access a kid's grandparents through by `@kid.grandparents`. Then you can generate the select field:

```
<%= g_f.collection_select(:name ,@kid.grandparents, :id, :name) %>
```